# Removing a element null inside a Array in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to remove a null element inside my array.

```
item: [{Object}, null, {Object}]

DB.updateMany(
  {},
  { $pull: { item: null }},
  { safe: true, upsert: true },
  function (err, doc) {
    console.log(doc)
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);

Error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Without success, any suggestion?

Is possible to prevent on Mongo Model to not create a null item inside an array?

Comment: An input document: `{ "_id" : 1, "items" : [ { "a" : 1 }, null, { "a" : 2 } ] }`. The following update removes the `null` from `items` array: `db.test.updateMany({}, { $pull: { items: null } } )`, in `mongo` shell.

Comment: Doenst work with my example.

Comment: Error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: I had tried with MongoDB v 4.2.8

Comment: What is the `Object` in `{Object}` ?

Comment: Something like this: { name: 'ABC',  age: 12, { address: { number: 10 } }

Comment: I understand you.. was looking everywhere, this should work.